# Alpine.js not being detected on the page after being loaded with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

Alpine.js is not being detected on the page after being loaded with Laravel Mix.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('tailwindcss'),
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ]
    ).version().sourceMaps();
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import 'alpinejs';
```

I tried doing `require(alpinejs)`, but it had the same effect.

I've added my js file to a blade template.

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

I also tried linking to /public/js/app.js without using the `mix()` helper. No effect, but Alpine.js doesn't get detected, and it doesn't work (so it's not an error with Alpine.js dev tools). However, adding Alpine via a CDN works just fine, so the problem must be with Laravel Mix. My public/js.app file is here:

https://gist.github.com/jardayn/2a25cdbed23a7b78e48da596a1eefe9e

Comment: Have you read https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation#as-a-module?

Comment: @SuperDJ no I haven't.  Thanks. You can post your response as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation#as-a-module) of Alpine 3 you need to initialize it.

After installing alpinejs with `npm install alpinejs`. You can initialize it with:

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

window.Alpine = Alpine

Alpine.start()
```

Comment: It truly depends on  the version that Igor is using. This is for Alpine 3, but his syntax is valid for Alpine 2.

Comment: Using Alpine 3. This fixed my issue. Thanks SuperDJ